# When will XHR revert to GET requests?

Tags: meteor, xmlhttprequest

I have a Meteor 1.2 app running on a server (using nginx as a proxy), that for various reasons, doesn't support DDP.  In this case, the app falls back to XHR polling and works as expected.  I also have it deployed live with the environment variable `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=1` to dully disable websockets, which I can verify with Chrome's network tab.

I have gotten some bug reports of sporadic problems that I cannot reproduce.

It looks like that in some cases, forms submissions don't use a POST, but revert to a GET (ie, I can see all of the form data in the URL) and the form doesn't submit at all.

Under what circumstances can XHR in Meteor revert from POST to GET?  Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this and and not seeing anything in the logs that would suggest a problem.

Comment: how do you submit your form? Can you share that code?

Comment: Do you use jQuery for the xhr ? and in that case, do you use $.post when the user submit the form ? like @christianFritz, we need the html code of the form, and the js that manage the submit/post

Comment: @ChristianFritz It's a MeteorJS AutoForm, and like much with Meteor, the plumbing between components if handled by the framework itself.  I'll see if I can extract any meaningful code.

Comment: @Rebolon It's a Meteor app, so that is provided by the framework via Autoforms.  IIRC, Metor's DDP layer is built on WebSockets; if WS aren't available (like in my case), emulation is done with SockJS.

Comment: 1. Check if the user's browser is still supported by Meteor (some people just cling to IE 6). 2. Check if there are any user scripts or browser extensions (think AdBlocker) that could be disrupting your code in whatever way.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've viewed the actual headers of the failed form request, which may probably mean you are making an assumption the request is a GET. If I'm mistaken, please correct me. If you are unable to see the headers, add some custom logging that differentiates between POST and GET so you can clarify it is in fact a GET.

I would think that the post is failing somehow and you are missing the error catch. Try to go into the logic on the server that handles the form post, and create some try catch blogs and do some custom logging. That could expose an error that you might be missing server-side. Additionally, make sure you have logging enabled in your database. An error could be occurring in the database that you might be missing. And if this doesn't work, at least you'll have a better error monitoring setup!

Comment: I see all of the form parameters being passed through the URL, which is why I am assuming this is a GET and not a POST, but you are correct that I didn't look at the actual headers.  I can't reproduce the problem, which is why this is difficult to debug.  I am also downvoting this because the question has a bounty on it, this was added after the bounty, and I don't think this is a good answer for an auto-award.

Comment: Understood. It may be difficult to debug because you may not have appropriate debugging mechanisms in place. This was why my recommendation is to add some exception catch blocks and monitor database logging to make sure an exception is not causing the problem. Your basis that Meteor is sending a POST versus a GET only holds if you know that it is actually a POST. You said you were assuming which is sending you down a false road.